# What is the most efficient way to create a pixelated game with Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, pixel

This is a simple example of how I draw a pixelated image in my game:

```
SCALE = 6

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()

        texture = self.load_some_texture()
        texture.min_filter = 'nearest'
        texture.mag_filter = 'nearest'

        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Scale(SCALE)
            self.pixelart = Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=(0, 0), size=(64, 64))
            PopMatrix()

        return parent
```

**Is this the best and most efficient way to make a pixelated game in Kivy? If not, what is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with self.canvas:
    Scale(6)
    self.pixelart = Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=(0, 0), size=(64, 64))
```

I think you're fighting the widget system a bit - instead of doing this, why not leave out the scale, set the Rectangle pos/size to the widget pos/size (and make a binding so that it follows the widget pos/size when they change), and then set the widget pos and size to change everything at once. This way the widget will work as expected, as everything tracks it. Or if you want the button to be a widget that behaves normally, you could put your pixel drawings in a different Widget that doesn't have any normal behaviour of its own.

For resetting scale (and other matrix instructions), you can put your scale changes between `PushMatrix` and `PopMatrix` canvas instructions.

Comment: I didn't draw the pixelart inside the Button, but inside `MyApp`. Sorry if this was unclear. I updated my question and used `Push`- and `PopMatrix`. Thanks! Could you give my question another try?

Comment: The App doesn't have a canvas, so that code won't work. More generally, you have the right idea though - if you want to load an image without interpolation between pixels, you must set these properties on the appropriate texture. You may find it convenient to make your own subclasses that do it automatically.